# using itertools to reduce the complexity of four "for" stmt?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have list 4 lists:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = range(0,4), range(4,9), range(8,15), range(2,16)
# just using range() generate sample data
```

I can list all the items combination by sequence `list1_item, list2_item, list3_item, list4_item` via below code:

```
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        for item3 in list3:
             for item4 in list4:
                   print [item1, item2, item3, item4]
```

May I know if I can do this job via `itertools` module?

Thanks

Comment: next time, please mention what you have tried already.

Comment: ok, will follow your suggestion

Comment: ugghhhh, this is a great question. oh what they changed the question upvote/downvote criteria -.- +1 anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
for n in itertools.product(list1, list2, list3, list4):
    print n
```

(`n` will be a tuple instead of a list).

Comment: Thanks, i realized my mistake by your code: my testing stmt `itertools.product((list1, list2, list3, list4))` should be  `itertools.product(*(list1, list2, list3, list4))`, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is itertools.product

```
import itertools
ret = list ( itertools.product( list1, list2, list3, list4 ) )
```

And ret is the result.